# Openquery select into VS insert into (SQL Server 2016) Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following SQL code to dynamically populate data into the tables but I now need to insert only. I am aware that select into also created the tables whereas insert simply populates existing tables.

Here is the SELECT INTO:

```
SET @SQL = 'Select * into destinationdb.stage.'+@Name + ' from    openquery("LINKEDSERVER", ' + '''SELECT * FROM source_db.' + @Name + ''');'
```

And  here is the INSERT INTO that I tried.

```
SET @SQL='insert into destinationdb.stage.'+@Name + ' * from  openquery("LINKEDSERVER", ' + '''SELECT * FROM source_db.' + @Name + ''');'
```

Which is of course gave me syntax errors.

I have tried many similar variations and am wondering if someone can spot my syntax error in the INSERT INTO?

Comment: is it because you cannot use * with the insert statement?!?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add schema after source_db, and remove * after insert into

```
SELECT * FROM source_db.dbo.tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @Name varchar(100)='tablename' 

SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(destinationdb.stage.'+@Name + ', ''SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 FROM db.table1'')'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out myself after a few more tries! 
This is what worked:

```
SET @SQL=' insert into destinationdb.stage.'+@Name + ' select * from  openquery("LINKEDSERVER", ' + '''SELECT * FROM sourcedb.' + @Name + ''');'
```